# validate dynamically created elements on select an option of combobox

Tags: jquery, plugins, validation

I am Using [jquery validate() plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) .
i hava a combobox in form that when user select an option on it then new element create dynamically .
now how do validate this new element according to selected option of combobox .
in fact i want first check the value of combobox then it's new elements created .
are you have any solution ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new element when the user select an option then you can do the validation right after that? (but shouldn't you validate first and then create a new element?)

http://jsfiddle.net/gGB6C/

```
<div id="test">
    <select id="ComboBox1">
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="3">Value 3</option>
        <option value="4">Value 4</option>
    </select>
</div>

$("#ComboBox1").change(function() {
    var text = $('<input type="text"></input>');
    $('#test').append(text);
    text.validate();
});
```

Or do you mean that you want the same behaviour with the 2 comboboxes. E.g. User selects option in ComboBox1, which will create ComboBox2. The user selects an options and will create ComboBox3?

(In short, can you rephrase the question?)

Comment: yes . i create new elements when the user select an option then i want do the validation on this new Elements after that.

Comment: I've added an example. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.live()

http://api.jquery.com/live/